# How to escape "this" problem in a javascript class?

Tags: javascript, class, this

```
get_O3(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    let station = document.getElementById(e.target.id);

    let lon = station.getAttribute('lon');

    let lat = station.getAttribute('lat');

    let code_station = station.getAttribute('code');

    this.get_previsions(lon, lat, "O3").bind(this).then((data) => 
    {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

I have a "this" problem, when i call the function get_previsions i get the error :
 Uncaught TypeError: this.get_previsions is not a function. 
It might be because of the (e) parameter because when i do a console.log(this) it returns the target. I would like that this == my class.
Thanks for the help

Comment: I mean "this" is referring to local scope, I am not sure what the issue is.  Where is the get_provisions function?  Why not simply make it func get_provisions() and then call get_provisions() from inside the get_03 function. Alternatively you could pass "this" as a parameter into the get_03 function by doing something like get_03(e, _this) and then do _this.get_provisions. I am assuming with e.preventDefault its being called from a button click?

Comment: I've no idea why you think `this.get_previsions ` should exist. We can't see where you define `get_previsions`, or how you call `get_O3` (which would determine what the value of `this` is). You need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At any given point you can check what the current `this` reference is pointing to by doing the 4 following rules:

1. **New**: Was the function called using `new` then the `this` points to the new instance.
2. **Explicit Binding**: Was the function called using `Function#call`, `Function#apply` or `Function#bind`
3. **Implicit Binding**: Was the function called by its owner? (i.e. `owner.foo()` or `owner["bar"]()`)
4. **Default Rule**: If none of the other rules happen then `this` is set to the `window` object if the script is running in `"use strict"` mode otherwise `undefined`.

Event-listeners call a function using Explicit binding (`callBack.call(target, ...)`) so the `this` reference gets set to the target. To change the `this` reference you either need to wrap it and call it implicitly or use `Function#bind`.

Implicit call Example (+ closure):

```
var something = {
  foo: function() {
    var self = this;
    addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      self.bar(e);
    });
  },
  bar: function() {

  }
};
```

Explicit call Example (Function#bind):

```
var something = {
  foo: function() {
    addEventListener("click", this.bar.bind(this));
  },
  bar: function() {

  }
};
```

Comment: @Dudy83 Both ways should work. Also if the answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking the check-mark on its left.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a class defined similar to

```
class thing {
  get_O3(e) { ... },
  get_previsions() { ... }
}
```

There are a few options for you. First option, you can bind all functions to `this` in the constructor:

```
class thing {
  constructor () {
    this.get_03 = this.get03.bind(this);
    this.get_previsions = this.get_previsions.bind(this);
  }
  get_O3(e) { ... },
  get_previsions() { ... }
}
```

This can get awkward, especially if you have many functions. You can write a helper `bindAll` function, but a less awkward/verbose solution is to use a factory method instead, bypassing `this` altogether:

```
function makeThing {
  const thing = {
    get_O3(e) {
      ...
      thing.get_previsions();
    },
    get_previsions() { ... }
  };
  return thing;
}
```

[Eric Elliot on Medium](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-with-es6-4d224591a8b1) has some good reading on the topic if you want to get more in depth.

Comment: what's `this.bind` on an instance of `thing`?

Comment: The bind() method creates a new function that has its `this` keyword set to the value in the first argument. Called from the `constructor` function, `bind` ensures that all instances of `this` refer to the created instance.

Comment: you're talking about `Function#bind`, but you're trying to use `thing#bind` which is not defined. `this.get_03 = this.get03.bind(this);`

Comment: D'oh. Thanks. Corrected.